# check if redirect to current page express

Tags: node.js, express

I have requests timing out because they are trying to redirect to the current page. how would you first check the url to make sure it is not trying to redirect to the current page and just return instead? 
an example

```
exports.home = (req, res) => {
    redirect('/');
};

app.get('/',route.home);
```

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly.

Comment: show me the code. Coffee's for closers!

Comment: Which part is unclear? Redirecting to the url that you are currently on, in express, times out or throws a 503 service unavailable. How would you catch the attempt to redirect to the current url and just return

Comment: I just want to catch if the request is trying to redirect to the url that it is currently coming from before it tries to redirect to itself. Forgive me I'm not understanding what more information could be provided the explain what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `req.originalUrl` to get the full url that is on the request or `req.path` to get just the path which I believe that you are looking for.

I think the  bigger problem is that you're never sending a response at all. I'm unsure of your use case, but try sending a response instead. For example, if you have a `'home'` view:

```
exports.home = (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
};

app.get('/',route.home);
```

Comment: Thank you req.path is what i was looking for. That is just psudeo code to elaborate on my question.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Well glad it helped!